# gsutil permission in Ansible

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ansible, gsutil

I would like to use `gsutil` as a `command` in Ansible (2.5.X).
On the managed server I already setup Cloud access (service account).
When I use `gsutil` on the machine, it works without problems.
But when I create a playbook on my management machine and try to 
run SDK command I have no access to cloud and permission denied
errors.

I suspect that SSH connection and environment is handled in
a specific way by Ansible. Could someone help me how to use SDK commands in Ansible?

```
- name: use ansible command
  command: >
    gsutil list gs://project.something.com
```

I know that there is [gs_storage](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/gc_storage_module.html) module. But I do not know
where to look for `gs_access_key` in an already configured setup.
In `.config/gcloud`? I'm still learning the Cloud, so some of this
things are new to me. The Cloud access was setup using `.json` key,
but after I delete this key from the managed machine (shouldn't be exposed).

Best Regards
Kamil

Answer (score 1):

`gsutil list` would at least require role `Viewer` assigned to the instance service account - or `roles/storage.objectViewer`, in case it should also be able to get files from a bucket. [Providing Credentials as Module Parameters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/scenario_guides/guide_gce.html#providing-credentials-as-module-parameters) shows how to authenticate with the `gcp_compute_instance` module - also see the [Cloud Storage IAM Roles](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles) and [Cloud Storage Authentication](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication) (the scopes).

Comment: I wrote that I setup the access before running the playbook. I have a special `serviceaccount` with appropriate permissions. `gsutil ls gs://bucket` works on the server. I can list and download buckets. What I can't is running the same command over Ansible from another computer.

Comment: Thanks! That looks like somethig that might work; I wonder why I did not find it, I googled a lot of "ansibe gcloud" and other combinations.

Comment: And, I would like to learn why is that. Do you know a good low lewel doc that explains what is happening. I know that SDK looks for credentials in `.config/gcloud` (probably), but I do not know why that is not possible when using Ansible. It is also impossible to get remote users `$HOME` -- I'm using a `user` module to `register` uesr's env. Probably a similar problem, but I can't find good info.

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html ...might help; just see under which user you have Ansible running - which might have a whole other `~` home directory.

Comment: I use a lot of `become` when running tasks that should be run by a specific user. I think those problems are realted to how SSH and shells/subshells are handled in Ansible, but I'm still searching for a good explanation.